# Firebase - Data structure issue for extracting an object from nested structure

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

Firebase - Data structure issue for extracting an object from nested structure.

I want to find the uid and then check if the key is a jobId.
I've labelled accordingly below.

I'm using typescript and angular2 with firebase.

**This is my current attempt that returns "null":**

```
        var jobId = "-K5fIAiuHM-4xeEQJiIS";
        var uid = "3f61ae7a-99a1-4cbf-9c8e-00b2249956a7";

        var userRef = this.refApp.child('key').child(uid);
        var query = userRef.child('jobId').child(jobId);

        query.on('value', (snap) => {

            //This returns null
            var response = snap.val();
        });
```

**This is my database structure:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure is `/applications/$userId/$jobId`. Use those keys to get to your data.

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/kahemeziwu/edit?js,console)**

```
var jobId = "-K5fIAiuHM-4xeEQJiIS";
var uid = "3f61ae7a-99a1-4cbf-9c8e-00b2249956a7";
var refApp = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>/applications');
var jobRef = refApp.child(uid).child(jobId);
jobRef.on('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
```

Right now you're using `"key"`, which I believe is from my previous demo. That's just for show, not for your actual solution. Keep your data structure in mind when reading the sample code, because it can vary.

Comment: Hi, that still returned null

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean for the quotes around `'jobId'`. Updated.

Comment: How would I push to that structure?

Comment: `refApp.child(uid).push()`

Comment: Hi David, that worked but made a new id for jobid - it needs to push based on the job id key?

Comment: I've tried this - this.refApp.child(this.uid).child(job.id).push(this.application);

Comment: Need details on what `this.application` is. Can you post another question?

Comment: Yeh sure il do that now - 1 sec

Comment: Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382697/firebase-push-an-object-in-a-nested-list-of-objects