# Firebase - push an object in a nested list of objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

Firebase - push an object in a nested list of objects

**Current attempt:**

```
this.application.userUid = this.uid;
this.application.companyUid = job.uid;
this.application.jobName = job.name;
this.application.jobDescription = job.description;
this.application.jobId = job.id;

this.refApp.child(this.uid).child(job.id).push(this.application);
```

Currently the object is added but nested too low down. It needs to be like the second object in the list.

uid --> jobid -> then the object.

**Here is my database:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.set()`, instead of `.push()`

```
this.refApp.child(this.uid).child(job.id).set(this.application);
```

However, if you want to generate an id with `.push()` you can move back one level in the data structure:

```
this.refApp.child(this.uid).push(this.application);
```

Comment: That worked from a structure point of view but it still made a new id. The id needs to be the jobId

Comment: I need to use my jobId instead of firebase making me a new id

Comment: maybe i use set instead?

Comment: Are you trying to update or create a new object? Because push will create a new child and update will update the values.

Comment: Got it working now with set : this.refApp.child(this.uid).child(job.id).set(this.application);

Comment: I think you'll want to use `.update()` instead of `.set()`. The `.set()` method is destructive, meaning it will delete all existing properties at that location. The `.update()` method will just update any additional changes.

Comment: I need to use set because its adding an object vs update

Comment: Ah, I see. `.set()` works then. I've updated my answer.