# AngularFire query on multiple fields

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project which needs to select data from **Firebase** on **multiple fields**.

I have a firebase database like this:

```
[{
    date: "2016-01-29"
    done: false
    task: "hello world"
},
{
    date: "2016-01-29"
    done: false
    task: "hello world"
}]
```

Now I want to query all data with **date** is today and **done** is true.

I look around google for a while but there's nothing work. Is there any one can please help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only query on a single property with Firebase queries. So either you'll have to do the rest of the filtering client-side or you'll have to combine the values into a single 'date_done' property.

```
[{
    date: "2016-01-29",
    done: false,
    date_done: "2016-01-29_false",
    task: "hello world1"
},
{
    date: "2016-01-29",
    done: false,
    date_done: "2016-01-29_false",
    task: "hello world"
}]
```

Now you can get all the queries that were done on January 29 with:

```
ref.orderByChild('date_done').equalTo('2016-01-29_true').on(...
```

For some more information from people who asked similar questions, see:

- [NoSQL database design for queries with multiple restrictions (Firebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336697/nosql-database-design-for-queries-with-multiple-restrictions-firebase)
- [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)
- [Firebase - How do I write multiple orderByChild for extracting data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374816/firebase-how-do-i-write-multiple-orderbychild-for-extracting-data)
- [How to do the following query in Firebase? (more than one where condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432030/how-to-do-the-following-query-in-firebase-more-than-one-where-condition)
- [Filter products on multiple child properties in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538312/filter-products-on-multiple-child-properties-in-firebase)

Comment: Thanks Frank a lot. I figure out what need to do with the issues. I have to redesign my database and add some fields for further purpose.